# Power inverter beeping

Tags: batteries, inverter, solar-energy

I have two batteries 12V/100Ah connected in parallel and a 500W inverter connected to them. The batteries are charged from PV panels through a charge controller.

Although I connect a little device such a lamp (40W) or Chromecast to the inverter, it will start to beep after 3 min aprox.

At this very moment (night) the inverter won't even turn ON. So either the battery or inverter are dead but don't know how can I make sure of it.

Additional questions:

The connection from the inverter to the batteries are made by [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoYq3.jpg). Could the little surface contact affect?

A battery of these characteristic is supposed to drop around 2 volts immediatly after connecting a load? If that's the case maybe the inverter shouldn't work just below 12 V?

Comment: could be a bad cell.   IT can drop quickly from charge at 14.2 to 12.5V with no charge at 100% SoC and 40A   .. Two 100AH batteries should have a CCA combined total of 1600A @ 7.5V so 40A or 500W should not be a problem.  All it takes some battery maintenance. Can you check Specific Gravity in each cell. ?

Comment: Measure the voltage at rest and under your 40 W load.

Answer (score 2):

Lead acid batteries should never get below 10.5V if they do, then they are dead. Corroded contacts can cause resistance problems and cause the voltage to drop. But if your measuring the voltage directly on the terminal this will not matter. The batteries are probably dead.

[image]